# Niveau von "drum"

Tags: word-usage, usage

Aus dem [*Süddeutschen Zeitung*](https://zeitung.sueddeutsche.de/szdigital/public/file/sz/2015-01-28/3/preview/index.html):

> Die Bundeswehr braucht junge Leute. **Drum** hat sie jetzt einen "Showroom" in Berlin. Noch kann man nicht sagen, dass die Bevölkerung hier Schlange stünde.

Wie formell klingt das Wörtchen "drum"? Ist es tatsächlich eine gute Idee, dieses Wort in einem Zeitungsartikel zu verwenden?

Comment: Da werde ich mal close-voten weil das eine Frage des persönlichen Geschmack ist :)... besonders formell klingt es nicht, aber "whatever".

Comment: @Emanuel Ich habe gedacht, dass alle sagen würden, es ist zu informell. Wenn auch andere Leute empfinden, dass diese Frage zu subjektiv ist, dann habe ich kein Problem damit, sie schließen zu lassen.

Comment: Naja, sagen wir mal so... im gleichen Satz wird das Wort "Showroom" verwendet. Das "drum" ist sozusagen Teil des mit stilistischen Mitteln ausgedrückten ironischen Seitenhiebs auf die Möchte-Gern-Coole-Werbekampagne der Bundeswehr.

Comment: Jo, @Emanuel, mach draus mal ne Antwort.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ich finde es nicht besonders formell, deshalb würde man es z.B. in einer Doktorarbeit sicher nicht verwenden. Aber die Süddeutsche ist ein Journal und gibt Nachrichten, im einordnenden Sinne, wertend wieder. Genau das ist häufig, im Gegensatz zu reinen informativen Nachrichten, mit einer gewissen stilistischen Freiheit verbunden.

Comment: Und in welchem Fach schwebt Dir solch eine Doktorarbeit vor, oder würdest Du in keinem Fach "drum" verwenden? P.S.: Sich auf einen Kommentar zu beziehen in der Antwort ist heikel, denn die werden häufiger mal gelöscht, aka aufgeräumt oder soll ich sagen: Gesäubert.

Comment: Das war bloß ein Beispiel dafür, dass man _drum_ vielleicht nicht unbedingt verwenden sollte, wenn etwas sachlich gehalten werden muss.

Comment: @userunknown.. auf die Gefahr hin, wie ein Idiot (he)rüberzukommen aber willst du mit den Kommentaren andeuten, dass "drum" in einer Doktorarbeit vorkommen könnte? Ich habe in einer Ingeneurswissenschaft meine Magisterarbeit geschrieben und ich musste mir für deutliche formalere Sachen sagen lassen, mein Stil wäre "journalistisch". Ergo... ich kann Benjoyo in der Hinsicht nur zustimmen. Allerdings bin ich verwirrt, dass die Süddeutsche ein Journal ist. Für mich ist es eine Zeitung, wenngleich der Hipsterfaktor ziemlich hoch ist.

Comment: @Emanuel Darüber lässt sich sicher streiten, aber für mich sind Süddeutsche, FAZ und Co. Journale.

Comment: Was ist denn für dich dann eine Zeitung?

Comment: Etwas wo dieser meinungsbildende Aspekt nicht so deutlich zum Vorschein kommt, sei es, weil es an journalistischer Qualität fehlt oder einfach weil das nicht gewollt wird. Ist halt wie mit _heute_ und _heute journal_. (Wobei Jounale natürlich auch gleichzeitig Zeitungen sind ;) )

Comment: @Emanuel: Ich kenne eine Doktorarbeit (Literaturwissenschaft) die auch als Sachbuch erschienen ist, da kommen weit saloppere Formulierungen vor.

Answer (score 5):

Die Kontraktion "drum" hat eindeutig das Flair lässig gesprochener Umgangsprache.
Zusammen mit dem Konjunktiv "stünde"  wirken die beiden Stilebenen nicht gerade sehr stilistisch. Ich meine das "drum ist hier eigentlich fehl am Platz. Aber ein Journalist kann schreiben wie er will, manchmal merkt man aber, dass das Stilempfinden nicht besonders ausgeprägt ist. Dürfte aber auch mit Zeitdruck und Hektik im Pressewesen zusammenhängen. Und wir wissen natürlich nicht, unter welchem Zeitdruck manche Artikel geschrieben wurden.

Answer (score 1):

Neben *drum* gibt es noch weitere analog verkürzte Adverbien:

- [dran](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/dran) (daran)
- [drauf](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/drauf) (darauf)
- [drein](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/drein) (darein)
- [drin](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/drin) (darin)
- [drüber](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/drueber) (darüber)
- [drum](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/drum) (darum)
- [drun­ter](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/drunter) (darunter)

Laut *Duden* gehören alle zur Umgangssprache und nicht zur geschrieben Form des Hochdeutsch.